# How to use opencv with cuda support python?

Tags: python, opencv

I found example of cuda accelerated opencv python code in official opencv github repository. 
[test_cuda.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/python/test/test_cuda.py)

```
cuMat1 = cv.cuda_GpuMat()
cuMat2 = cv.cuda_GpuMat()
cuMat1.upload(npMat1)
cuMat2.upload(npMat2)

cuMat1 = cv.cuda.cvtColor(cuMat1, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
cuMat2 = cv.cuda.cvtColor(cuMat2, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

But I found that module 'cv2.cuda' has no attribute 'cvtColor'.

My opencv build information:

```
NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.0, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
NVIDIA GPU arch:             61
NVIDIA PTX archs:            61
```

[Full build information](https://pastebin.com/U7v12Vhm)

How to fix it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/U7v12Vhm

Comment: Which version you built, please?

Answer (score -2):

You should change like this.

```
cuMat1 = cv.cuda_GpuMat()
cuMat2 = cv.cuda_GpuMat()

npMat1_n = cv.cvtColor(npMat1, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
npMat2_n = cv.cvtColor(npMat2, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

cuMat1.upload(npMat1_n)
cuMat2.upload(npMat2_n)
```

Comment: This performs cvtColor on the CPU, not on the GPU.